# html - selection range - getting the range + starting node + ending node + distance

Tags: javascript, html, select, range, dhtml

From my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950038) for selecting specific html text, I have gone through [this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) to understand range in html string.

For selecting a specific text on html page. We need to follow this steps.

Assumed HTML:

```
<h4 id="entry1196"><a
    href="http://radar.oreilly.com/archives/2007/03/call_for_a_blog_1.html"
    class="external">Call for a Blogger's Code of Conduct</a></h4>

<p>Tim O'Reilly calls for a Blogger Code of Conduct. His proposals are:</p>

<ol>
    <li>Take responsibility not just for your own words, but for the
        comments you allow on your blog.</li>
    <li>Label your tolerance level for abusive comments.</li>
    <li>Consider eliminating anonymous comments.</li>
</ol>
```

java script to make selection by range

```
var range = document.createRange();  // create range
var startPar = [the p node];         // starting parameter 
var endLi = [the second li node];    // ending parameter
range.setStart(startPar,13);         // distance from starting parameter.
range.setEnd(endLi,17);              // distance from ending parameter
range.select();                      // this statement will make selection
```

I want to do this in invert way. I mean, assume that selection is done by user on browser (safari). My question is that How can we get starting node (as we have 'the p node' here) and ending node (as we have 'the second li node' here) and the range as well (as we have 13,17 here)?

Edit : my efforts (From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887101))

```
    var sel = window.getSelection();

    if (sel.rangeCount < 1) {
        return;
    }
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var startNode = range.startContainer, endNode = range.endContainer;

    // Split the start and end container text nodes, if necessary
    if (endNode.nodeType == 3) {
        endNode.splitText(range.endOffset);
        range.setEnd(endNode, endNode.length);
    }

    if (startNode.nodeType == 3) {
        startNode = startNode.splitText(range.startOffset);
        range.setStart(startNode, 0);
    }
```

But, yet I am confused about getting like, if selected is first paragraph or second or third, or selected is in first heading or second heading or what....

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: @Tim Down - let me explain. User makes selection & taps on a button. I need to store the range that user has selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storing the selected range is simple. The following will return only the first selected range (Firefox at least supports multiple selections):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getSelectionRange() {
    var sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            return sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    }
    return null;
}

var range;

</script>
<input type="button" onclick="range = getSelectionRange();"
    value="Store selection">
```

`range` will have properties `startContainer` (the node containing the start of the range), `startOffset` (an offset within the start container node: a character offset in the case of text nodes and child offset in elements), `endContainer` and `endOffset` (equivalent behvaiour to the start properties). `Range` is well documented by [its specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) and [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range).

In IE, `range` will contain a `TextRange`, which works very differently. Rather than nodes and offsets, TextRanges are concerned with characters, words and sentences. Microsoft's site has some documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533042%28VS.85%29.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28VS.85%29.aspx.

Comment: but range is javascript kind of variable. How can I write to file using objective c. I know it's a new question. I am asking it.

Comment: How are you proposing to get your JavaScript talking to Objective-C? I assume this is an iPhone/iPad project we're taling about, so you're only interested in Mobile Safari?

Comment: Yes Exactly - I am developing an iPhone application. Now, i am in one more trouble that how to store java variable in iphone application.