# Get character position inside non input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

If i clicked on the 'w' character using a **mousedown** jQuery event, how can i convert the **e.pageX** to the correct character position inside the paragraph element?

Comment: Really What do you wanna do with That...... :D

Comment: I want to make a simple text annotator, so i want to be able to select whatever text there's regardless of any styling element that exists. I tried looking the window.getSelection but i don't know how would that help.

Comment: Perhaps this question is the simple case of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955244/html-selection-range-getting-the-range-starting-node-ending-node-dista?rq=1