# Alternative for execCommand('underline');

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Okay, some Guys will know what i mean and edit my Question but they did it wrong.

A better explanation:

You have a contenteditable `div` with the text `This is a Test String.`.
If you use now the `execCommand('underline')` on `Test String` you get `This is a <u>Test String</u>`
if you use now the `execCommand('strikethrough')` on `is a Test` you get `This <s>is a <u>Test</u></s><u>String</u>`, THIS is correct.

So, in HTML5 `<u>` and `<s>` are obsolete.
For the first `execCommand` you can use the `surroundContents()` with a `<span style="text-decoration:underline;">`. If you now use the `surroundContets()` for the second `execCommand` you receive the `BAD_BOUNDARYPOINTS_ERR`.

The Thing i want is a Function which works like the `execCommand` in this case but with functions where i can define with witch HTML-Tag the String will wrapped… (It should be intelligent in the case if there is any overlapping…)

Comment: There's something involved here besides Javascript and HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `surroundContents()` will have problems: if the selection encompasses multiple block elements, such as `<div>`s or `<p>`s, the surrounded contents will be placed in a new block, breaking it out of its original position. To overcome this, you could easily adapt my answer here: [apply style to range of text with javascript in uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887101/apply-style-to-range-of-text-with-javascript-in-uiwebview/2888969#2888969)

You'll need to do the following:

- Create a CSS class with the rule "text-decoration: underline;"
- Add an `intersectsNode` method of `Range` for browsers that don't have it, such as Firefox (see MDC for an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.intersectsNode)
- If you care about IE, you'll need to write a completely different solution.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. And… it works in Safari, i don't need more. :D

Answer (score 0):

CSS `text-decoration: underline`.

Comment: Very nice, haha, i don't tagged CSS
i know how its working in CSS to make a Underline,…
The Question is about an Alternativ for the execCommand('underline')

Comment: It is a real alternate, since it goes around this issue even if tag order is incorrect.

Comment: You also can put your command into `try..catch` block to catch incorrect use error.