# wysiwyg contendeditable createRange surroundContents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a contenteditable div that I want users to be able to select a portion of, and then click a button to wrap a div with some class and styles around.

The div I want to wrap around:

```
var newNode = $('<div class=\'selectedFont\' style=\'text-align=center;\'>');
```

The methods I need to use are in the title, I'm looking for an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to this related question does what you need: [apply style to range of text with javascript in uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887101/apply-style-to-range-of-text-with-javascript-in-uiwebview/2888969#2888969)

Comment: Thank you. I used your code and it works well. Do you have a method for checking if the selection already has the class applied and doing the removeSpanWithClass onclick rather than applyClassToSelection.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. It could certainly be improved by adding a check for the each text node in the selection to see if it's already contained within a span of the relevant class to prevent ending up with multiple nested spans with the same class, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking. I am planning to work on this and probably produce a small library, so all suggestions welcome.

Comment: Yes that's it. In WYSIWYG editors, if you select a range, the editor checks whether or not it already has various styles applied to it. So if a button applies Style A, and the selected range already has style A, then the button onclick would remove Style A rather than apply it again. A library would be fantastic, thank you so much.